# Multiple Entity Framework migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, database-migration

Assuming that automatic migrations are disabled, if I have for instance, 4 migrations and just the first one was used to update the database:

```
XXX...XXX_mymigration_v1 - Migration 1
XXX...XXX_mymigration_v2 - Migration 2
XXX...XXX_mymigration_v3 - Migration 3
XXX...XXX_mymigration_v4 - Migration 4
```

1. If I run `Update-Database` it will the Migration 4 applied right?
2. Intermediate migrations (2 and 3) will be applied in sequence until it reach the migration4?
3. And after that, if I want to rollback to Migration 1, can I do it?

Comment: 1) yes 2) yes 3) yes, You can do rollback to any migration version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why no-one has answered this earlier.

1) Yes, `update-database` with no parameters will update to the latest migration.

2) Migrations are applied in sequence as per the timestamp prefixed to the file name containing the migration.

3) If you want to roll back to the first migration you execute `update-database -TargetMigration mymigration_v1`. Note that you do not need the timestamp when specifying the migration name.